# Pic 18f4550 capture mode

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic, pulse

I would like to measure a pulse using the pic 18f4550  in capture mode, this pulse is generated by the pic microcontroller itself, for this I use a function which plays the role of the XOR logic gate (you find the function that I've used below). with RC0 and RC2 the inputs and RC6 the signal output. the pulse leaving RC6 enters ccp2 to be measured.

[image]

The problem I found is that the ccp2 cannot detect the impulse generated by the microcontroller. I don't know if there are any conditions to connect the pins of the microcontroller or something.
If anyone has an answer or a hint to fix this, I will be grateful!
and if you have any questions feel free to ask .thanks !!

UPDATE: I changed some instructions in the code, now the RC6 output provides a signal. but my LCD does not display anything. the RC6 output is present below.

[image]

UPDATE 2: the while(1) in the xor() function blocking the rest of my program, so the program never get out of xor() and my LCD wont display anything. when I don't use the while loop in xor () my RC6 produce anything, the same for the LCD.
I don't know where the problem is, I did everything in my power to find the bug . but the system still not working!!!

I will leave the program as it is, so new readers can understand what I am talking about.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "osc_config.h"
#include "LCD_8bit_file.h"
#include <string.h>

    unsigned long comtage,capt0,x;
    char pulse[20];
    char cosinus[20];
    float period,dephTempo,deph,phi;
    
void init (){
   
   IRCF0         =1;     /* set internal clock to 8MHz */
    IRCF1         =1;
    IRCF2         =1;  
    
    PIE2bits.CCP2IE=1;
    PIR2bits.CCP2IF=0;  
    CCPR2          =0;         /*CCPR1 is capture count Register which is cleared initially*/
     
    T3CONbits.RD16=1;  
    T3CKPS0=0;
    T3CKPS1=0;
    TMR3CS=0;
    
    TMR3IF=0; 
    
    T3CCP2=0; /*Timer3 is the capture clock source for CCP2*/
}

void xor()
{
    while(1)
        {
  if (PORTCbits.RC0==PORTCbits.RC2)
          {
           PORTCbits.RC6=0;
           }
        else if (PORTCbits.RC0!=PORTCbits.RC2)
              {
               PORTCbits.RC6=1;
               }   
  }
}
void main()
{
    
    TRISCbits.TRISC0=1;
    TRISCbits.TRISC2=1;
    TRISCbits.TRISC6=0;
    
    xor();
    LCD_Init();
     
      
    while(1)        
    {
    CCP2CON         = 0b00000101;
    PIR2bits.CCP2IF = 0;
    TMR3ON          = 0; 
    TMR3            = 0;

    while (!PIR2bits.CCP2IF);

    TMR3ON          = 1; 
    CCP2CON         = 0b00000100;
    PIR2bits.CCP2IF = 0;
    
    while (!PIR2bits.CCP2IF); 
    comtage = CCPR2; 
    
    dephTempo = (((float)comtage /30.518)/65536 );
    
    sprintf(pulse,"%.3f  ",dephTempo);
    LCD_String_xy(0,0,"the pulse width is : ");
    LCD_String_xy(2,9,pulse);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code that does not work.  It is not clear how the code fragment you posted generates a pulse.  You have not provided the code related to the timer.  You have not specified how you have connected the system.  What are you trying to measure - the width of the pulse?

Comment: sorry for not giving you enough information.
I am trying to measure a pulse generated by the microcontroller. but my lcd screen is not showing any information. even when i used oscilloscope i could not find signal on rc6.
 I added the code I used and a figure that shows my system. thanks!

Comment: NB: this problem occurs when I try to measure the pulse with the Deph_tempo () function.
the function that plays the role of XOR logic gate works fine when I use it alone.

Comment: You realize there's a while(1) in the xor() function blocking the rest of the whole program, yeah? Kind of hard to tell since your indention is a complete mess.

Comment: I added it cause I thought it would solve part of the problem. so without using it the RC6 does not produce anything.

Comment: Well you never get out of xor()... Of course your LCD wont display anything

Comment: @GabrielT when I don't use the while loop in xor () my RC6  produce anything, So I added it cause I thought it would solve part of the problem.

Comment: There are many ways to sample signals. Your xor() func blocks the entire app inconditionally. Here are some advises for you to sample two signals from RC0 and RC2 and implent XOR function without blocking the entire app:
> Use a periodic timer interrupt. Check input conditions and set the output state as needed within the timer interrupt service. The sample period must be at leas 4x that of the input freq.
> Use one of PORTB<7:4> interrupt on change feature to detect signal level changes and make your checks and sets.
> Use INT pins to detect signal edge changes and take the needed action